Recovering data from RAID1 array when QNAP hardware fails
My QNAP NAS has experienced a hardware failure and I need to get the data off the disks.
I am using RAID1.
I can successfully mount the drive in a linux machine (/dev/sdd) and it has five partitions:sdd1 through sdd5.
running:
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sddN

on each partition returns the description. Three partitions have superblocks.
I can run the following command successfully on the partitions that have superblocks and then I can mount the partitions and examine the contents:
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdd2 /dev/sdd5 --run

sdd5 seems to have all the the interesting storage. In here I cannot find and of the data from the /home directory where the user data is stored, nor is there anything in the /share directory. But I see everything else on the NAS from a system perspective.
I am unable to mount the partitions that do not have superblocks - so maybe the data is there????
Can you suggest any steps I am missing?

So after a bit of back and forth QNAP have said:
"Our storage structure cannot be mounted on a general Linux system. Please do not do such attempt manually. Otherwise the commands could change the information in disks and make them unable to recover on a new QNAP NAS. Thank you."
I don't want t buy another QNAP so I would like to have a crack at getting the data off.
Has anyone ever succeeded in getting data off a QNAP before?
